# How to add bold to the text that found in PatternFilter

Tags: java, swt, jface

I created `TreeViewer` and `PatternFilter`

```
PatternFilter patternFilter = new PatternFilter();
FilteredTree filter = new FilteredTree(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL, patternFilter, true);
treeViewer = filter.getViewer();

treeViewer.setContentProvider(new TreeContentProvider());
treeViewer.setLabelProvider(new TreeLabelProvider());
treeViewer.setAutoExpandLevel(AbstractTreeViewer.ALL_LEVELS);
treeViewer.setInput(Activator.getDefault().getTreeModel());

Tree tree = treeViewer.getTree();
```

How can I add bold text to the text results of the filter?

Like the filter in the preferences dialog in Eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Eclipse Preferences uses that same `FilteredTree`. Knowing this, it's easy from here.

A quick trip to `FilteredTree`, and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> the text `bold`.

First result is this method:

```
/**
 * Return a bold font if the given element matches the given pattern.
 * Clients can opt to call this method from a Viewer's label provider to get
 * a bold font for which to highlight the given element in the tree.
 * 
 * @param element
 *            element for which a match should be determined
 * @param tree
 *            FilteredTree in which the element resides
 * @param filter
 *            PatternFilter which determines a match
 * 
 * @return bold font
 */
public static Font getBoldFont(Object element, FilteredTree tree, PatternFilter filter)
```

If we search for where it's used, we find `org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.PreferenceBoldLabelProvider`.

Use the same trick in your label provider.

---

**Edit 1:** As [greg-449](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2670892/greg-449) said, I hope you're experienced enough to know not to use internal classes, rather immitate them and create your own by extending `LabelProvider` (in this case).

Comment: But beware that `PreferenceBoldLabelProvider` is in an **internal** package so should not really be used and may change without notice.

Comment: How did you found the class of the perference?

Comment: Also what did you mean in quick trip pus prrss cntrl f

Comment: How did you found the static method get BoldFont

Comment: @user1365697 I literally explained every step in my answer... I happen to know that Eclipse Preferences uses `FilteredTree`. I went to `FilteredTree` by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+T, and I search for the text "bold" with CTRL+F. That's how I found it.

Comment: One more thing the funcyoon getBoldFont should be set on the filter or I need to create LabelProvider and then set the style of bold

Comment: @user1365697 You'll need to use your own `LabelProvider`, yes.

Comment: But how i can know when to bold the text and when not to bold the text. Ithouht that the bold shold be on the filter

Comment: @user1365697 It's not your job to know, the method does that automatically.